# Nyquist Plot using Python with certain parameters

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, controls, nyquist

I am trying to draw the Nyquist plot using python but I have no clue what all parameters are required by python to do plot that curve.

Here is a glimpse of the parameters that I have:

```
Channel_ID,Step_ID,Cycle_ID,Test_Time,EIS_Test_ID,EIS_Data_Point,Frequency,Zmod,Zphz,Zreal,Zimg,OCV,AC_Amp_RMS 
4,7,1,36966.3072,0,0,200015.6,0.4933,70.9969,0.1606,0.4664,3.6231,0.35
4,7,1,36966.3072,0,1,158953.1,0.412,70.8901,0.1349,0.3893,3.6231,0.35
4,7,1,36966.3072,0,2,126234.4,0.3437,70.7115,0.1135,0.3244,3.6231,0.35
4,7,1,36966.3072,0,3,100265.6,0.2869,70.6312,0.0951,0.2706,3.6231,0.35
4,7,1,36966.3072,0,4,79640.63,0.2364,70.2418,0.0799,0.2224,3.6231,0.35
```

and above are the values to those parameters.

Based on the above parameters that are
 `Test_Time, Frequency, Zmod, Zphz, Zreal, Zimg, OCV, AC_Amp_RMS`  where `Zmod is the absolute value of Zreal and Zimg`, I need to draw a Nyquist plot. I have no clue how these parameters could be used for the plot.

PS: I tried to plot the curve by making use of the real and imaginary part that is `Zimg and Zreal`

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
train_df = pd.read_csv("above_data_with_around_100_rows.csv")
plt.figure()
plt.plot(train_df["Zreal"], train_df["Zimg"], "b")
plt.plot(train_df["Zreal"], -train_df["Zimg"], "r")
plt.show()
```

Can this be the useful for Nyquist plot?

Comment: See if any of these help [matplotlib nyquist plot site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=matplotlib+nyquist+plot+site:stackoverflow.com&sxsrf=AOaemvIh0-5bVf3gh_DxTlmNXISZ9CHBNg:1630932901474&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi3jPrBsuryAhVItZ4KHekRCFQQrQIoBHoECAwQBQ&biw=1920&bih=975)

Comment: Looks like there is a package for this https://python-control.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/control.nyquist_plot.html and see https://notebook.community/python-control/python-control/examples/bode-and-nyquist-plots

Comment: Yes, there is a package in Python. I looked it up but I am not sure of how the given data can be used to assign the values to the parameters that are required by those functions.